# Is there a CSS selector for "multiple lines"?

Tags: html, css

I have a (navigation) menu on my website like this:

```css
a
{
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Home</a>
<a href="#">Downloads</a>
<a href="#">Contact</a>
<a href="#">FAQ</a>
<a href="#">Disclaimer</a>
```

If the screen is wide enough, the menu will show in one single line.

But if the screen is not wide enough (e.g. for smartphones) there will be more lines.

Is there a CSS selector for this case?

For this example it would be enough to change the background color to green with such a selector.

Comment: No, Using CSS only, you can't do that. But using JS and CSS, you can

Comment: If you want to change the background color depending on screen size, yes you can using [css media query](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp).

Comment: I personally would work on the whole approach. Use an `<ul>` for a navbar and simply color the entire list (parent element)

Answer (score 5):

A kind of hacky idea in case you know your font values and more precisely the height of one line.

Resize the screen and see the magic:

```css
.nav {
  position:relative; /* relative here, no on the links */
  font-size:20px;
  line-height:1.2em; /* height of a line*/
  z-index:0;
} 

a {
  clip-path:inset(0); /* clip the pseudo element to the element size */
  display:inline-block;
  color:#fff;
  padding:0 10px;
}
a:before {
 content:"";
 position:absolute;
 z-index:-1;
 inset:0;
 background:
   /* green will get visible if 100% (height) is bigger than 1.2em (one line) */
   linear-gradient(green 0 0) 0/100% calc(100% - 1.2em),
   red;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
<a href="#">Home</a>
<a href="#">Downloads</a>
<a href="#">Contact</a>
<a href="#">FAQ</a>
<a href="#">Disclaimer</a>
</div>
```

Comment: It's a nice idea but because I want to change other properties than backup color I cannot use it.

Comment: @somega you said *For this example it would be enough to change the background color to green with such a selector.* hence my answer

Answer (score -2):

html:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="styleSheet3.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="nav">
        <a href="#" class="active"> Home</a>
        <a href="#">Downloads</a>
        <a href="#">Downloads </a>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
        <a href="#">FAQ</a>
        <a href="#">Disclaimer</a>
    </div>
    <div id="small_nav">
        <div id="header">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="48" width="48" viewBox="0 0 48 48">
                <g>
                    <path id="path1" transform="rotate(0,24,24) translate(9,13.0382820367813) scale(0.9375,0.9375)  "
                        fill="#1C9E51"
                        d="M1.230957,19.693036L30.768982,19.693036C31.506958,19.693036,32,20.185041,32,20.923019L32,22.154038C32,22.893054,31.506958,23.384999,30.768982,23.384999L1.230957,23.384999C0.49194336,23.384999,0,22.893054,0,22.154038L0,20.923019C0,20.185041,0.49194336,19.693036,1.230957,19.693036z M1.230957,9.8470059L30.768982,9.8470059C31.506958,9.8470059,32,10.339011,32,11.076989L32,12.30801C32,13.045987,31.506958,13.53903,30.768982,13.53903L1.230957,13.53903C0.49194336,13.53903,0,13.047025,0,12.30801L0,11.076989C0,10.339011,0.49194336,9.8470059,1.230957,9.8470059z M1.230957,0L30.768982,0C31.506958,-6.3337211E-08,32,0.49298194,32,1.2309594L32,2.4619804C32,3.1999579,31.506958,3.6930011,30.768982,3.6930013L1.230957,3.6930013C0.49194336,3.6930011,0,3.1999579,0,2.4619804L0,1.2309594C0,0.49298194,0.49194336,-6.3337211E-08,1.230957,0z" />
                </g>
            </svg>

        </div>


        <div id="content">
            <a href="#">Home</a>
            <a href="#">Downloads</a>
            <a href="#">Contact</a>
            <a href="#">FAQ</a>
            <a href="#">Disclaimer</a>
        </div>
</body>

</html>
```

and css:

```
body
{direction:rtl;
}
#nav {
   
   display: table;
   width: 100%
}
    
#nav  span a {
 
  

    display:block !important;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center
}
#nav span {
    display: block;
    text-align: center
}
#small_nav a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
   
 
}
a
{
  background:red;
}
   
#small_nav #content {
    display: none;
   
}
#small_nav:hover #content{display:block}
#small_nav {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none
}
@media screen and (max-width:600px) {
    #small_nav {
        display: block;
    }

    #nav {
        display: none
    }
}
```

A bit long, but I think it's good,
lots of success!

Comment: please use a [repro] and explain how you solve it and why you solve it that way.

Comment: i use two types nave to big screem and to phone ,

Comment: read the link... and that explaination is far from sufficient.

Comment: I read, I think this is the minimum I can provide

Comment: it is not a runnable stacksnippet and its far from being minimal. No need for the entire head element. No need for 2 navbars and a svg that wasnt asked for. You extended a 9 line code to around 100 lines.